# Q23 from AMC 2012

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $abc+ab+bc+ac+a+b+c=104$, and $a,b,c>0$, what is the value of  $ a^2 + b^2 +c^2$?

I tried to make $a,b,c$ the subject of the equation and tried to add them up but it's weird...
I also have lots of more questions which I will ask later from AMC 2012, it's more difficult than what I usually do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider

$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$$

if the problem is finding integer solutions.

Comment: So,(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=104+1,do I make a,b,c each the subject and get the solution?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Also note that $105=3\cdot 5\cdot 73$

Comment: How did you know that it could be factorise into that form of (a+1)(b+1)(c+1) when you add 1 to the equation?

Comment: By my experience :).

Comment: Thanks for your help!I learned a new identity!

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) =7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$$
Lets assume it is that order 
Anyways the end result does not get affected by the order

$$a = 6$$
$$b=2$$
$$c=4$$

So I guess the rest is trivial

Comment: So we have to guess what makes up 105?Is there a way to solve it through straight up alegbra?

Comment: Why do you assume $a$, $b$, $c$ must be positive integers?

Comment: Because a,b,c>0 ?But that's a good question!What if they are not positive integers or not even integers?Does that make a difference in the 'solution' to the question?

Comment: Wait so ,if b and c are negative numbers,wouldn't 
(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=7(-3)(-5)
where
 a+1=7,a=6
b+1=-3,b=-4
c=1=-5,c=-6

hence a^2 +b^2 +c^2 =36+16+36=88
wouldn't it be different if it's negative numbers?
Wow,that's interesting!!!

Comment: You are  right my intuition was wrong.So I guess it is justified in having the condition of positivity

Answer (score 0):

Given, $abc+ab+bc+ac+a+b+c=104$, and $a,b,c>0$

$abc+ab+bc+ac+a+b+c=104$
$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)-1=104$
$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=105$
$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=3\cdot5\cdot7$

Without the loss of generality, let $a\leq b\leq c$
$a+1=3, b+1=5, c+1=7$
$a=2, b=4, c=6$

$\;\therefore\;a^2+b^2+c^2=2^2+4^2+6^2$

Hence, $a^2+b^2+c^2=56$